# Remove several rows in QTableView + QAbstractItemModel

Tags: python, pyqt

I am having a trouble removing several rows on my QAbstractItemModel.

My problem is that if I select several rows, say row 1 and 3.

I then loop over my selected rows, and delete them. However after I deleted the row `1`, then row `3` becomes the row `2`, so I actually delete the row `4`.

Here is my method to retrieve the selected rows :

```
def get_selected_rows(self):
    view = self._view
    selection = view.selectionModel()
    return selection.selectedRows()
```

Here is my method to delete a specific row :

```
def delete_obj(self, row):
    self._model.removeRow(row.row())
```

And here is my method in my controller :

```
def on_delete_clicked(self):
    for selected_index in self._view.get_selected_rows():
        self._view.delete_obj(selected_index)
```

Is there any way to avoid recalculating all the indexes after each iteration of my loop ?

Comment: Item indexes become invalid as soon as the model is changed. Better to get a list if items you want to remove (which will stay constant) and get the index from an item each iteration of the loop. This is easier if you are using `QStandardItem` and `QStandardItemModel` though.

Answer (score 1):

I found a very simple solution, I just iterate on the `reversed` of my list, and it's fine :)

```
def on_delete_clicked(self):
    for selected_index in reversed(self._view.get_selected_rows()):
        self._view.delete_obj(selected_index)
```